# Multiline CSV: output on a single line, with double-quoted input lines, using a different separator

Tags: bash, csv, awk, multiline

I'm trying to get a multiline output from a CSV into one line in Bash.

My CSV file looks like this:

```
hi,bye
hello,goodbye
```

The end goal is for it to look like this:

```
"hi/bye", "hello/goodbye"
```

This is currently where I'm at:

```
INPUT=mycsvfile.csv
while IFS=, read col1 col2 || [ -n "$col1" ]
do
  source=$(awk '{print;}' | sed -e 's/,/\//g' )
  echo "$source";
done < $INPUT
```

The output is on every line and I'm able to change the , to a / but I'm not sure how to put the output on one line with quotes around it.

I've tried BEGIN:

```
source=$(awk 'BEGIN { ORS=", " }; {print;}'| sed -e 's/,/\//g' )
```

But this only outputs the last line, and omits the first hi/bye:

```
hello/goodbye
```

Would anyone be able to help me?

Comment: First, understand why the first line is omitted.  The while loop reads the first line, and awk reads the second line.  Why are you letting awk read from the same source as the while loop?

Answer (score 1):

Just do the whole thing (mostly) in awk.  The final sed is just here to trim some trailing cruft and inject a newline at the end:

```
< mycsvfile.csv awk '{print "\""$1, $2"\""}' FS=, OFS=/ ORS=", " | sed 's/, $//'
```

Comment: That awk command will produce output that doesn't have a terminating newline and so is not a POSIX "text file" and so YMMV with piping it to any other command (`sed` in this case) as it'll be relying on undefined behavior (per POSIX) at that point.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to install **[`trl`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trl)**, a utility of mine, the command can be simplified as follows:

```
input=mycsvfile.csv
trl -R '| ' < "$input" | tr ',|' '/,'
```

- `trl` transforms multiline input into double-quoted single-line output separated by `,<space>` by default.

  - `-R '| '` (temporarily) uses `|<space>` as the separator instead; this assumes that your data doesn't contain `|` instances, but you can choose any char. that you know not be part of your data.
- `tr ',|' '/,'` then translates all `,` instances (field-internal to the input lines) into `/` instances, and all `|` instances (the temporary separator) into `,` instances, yielding the overall result as desired.

---

#### Installation of `trl` from the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/trl) (Linux and macOS)

<sup>Note: Even if you don't use Node.js, `npm`, its package manager, works across platforms and is easy to install; try

[`curl -L https://git.io/n-install | bash`](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install)</sup>

With [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) installed, install as follows:

```
[sudo] npm install trl -g
```

**Note**:

- Whether you need `sudo` depends on how you installed Node.js and whether you've [changed permissions later](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions); if you get an `EACCES` error, try again with `sudo`.
- The `-g` ensures [*global* installation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally) and is needed to put `trl` in your system's `$PATH`.

#### Manual installation (any Unix platform with `bash`)

- Download [this `bash` script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/trl/stable/bin/trl) as `trl`.
- Make it executable with `chmod +x trl`.
- Move it or symlink it to a folder in your `$PATH`, such as `/usr/local/bin` (macOS) or `/usr/bin` (Linux).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS='/' -v ORS='"' '{$1=s ORS $1; s=", "; print} END{printf RS}' file
"hi/bye", "hello/goodbye"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a `bash` loop, which is invariably slow.

`sed` and `tr` can do this more efficiently:

```
input=mycsvfile.csv
sed 's/,/\//g; s/.*/"&", /; $s/, $//' "$input" | tr -d '\n'
```

- `s/,/\//g` uses replaces all (`g`) `,` instances with `/` instances (escaped as `\/` here).
- `s/.*/"&", /` encloses the resulting line in `"..."`, followed by `,<space>`:

  - regex `.*` matches the entire pattern space (the potentially modified input line)
  - `&` in the replacement string represent that match.
- `$s/, $//` removes the undesired trailing `,<space>` from the *final* line (`$`)
- `tr -d '\n'` then simply removes the newlines (`\n`) from the result, because `sed` invariably outputs each line with a trailing newline.

Note that the above command's single-line output will not have a trailing newline; simply append `; printf '\n'` if it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/,/,"/");gsub(/^|$/,"\"");b=b (NR==1?"":", ")$0}END{print b}' file
"hi/bye", "hello/goodbye"
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
{
    sub(/,/,"/")            # replace comma
    gsub(/^|$/,"\"")        # add quotes
    b=b (NR==1?"":", ") $0  # buffer to add delimiters
}
END { print b }             # output
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you just have 2 lines in your file? If you have alternating 2 line pairs, let me know in comments and I will expand for that general case. Here is a one-line `awk` conversion for you:

```
# NOTE: I am using the octal ascii code for the 
# double quote char (\42=") in my printf statement
$ awk '{gsub(/,/,"/")}NR==1{printf("\42%s\42, ",$0)}NR==2{printf("\42%s\42\n",$0)}' file
```

output:

```
"hi/bye", "hello/goodbye"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt in awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ ORS = " " }{ a++; gsub(/,/, "/"); gsub(/[a-z]+\/[a-z]+/, "\"&\""); print $0; if (a == 1){ print "," }}{ if (a==2){ printf "\n"; a = 0 } }'
```

Works also if your Input has more than two lines.If you need some explanation feel free to ask :)